# Does rank $m$ $m \times n$ matrix imply matrix of last $m$ columns is invertible?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I was told this is a very basic concept in linear algebra but I am not sure why it is true. Suppose $ [ \mathbf{D}_{\mathbf{x}} F(0),  \mathbf{D}_{\mathbf{y}} F(0) ]$ is an $1\times 2$ block matrix with "actual" dimension $m\times n$ if it is viewed not in block form. This matrix has rank $m$.

Why is it, that this fact implies that the $m\times m$ matrix $\mathbf{D}_{\mathbf{y}} F(0)$ is invertible? I thought that this would not imply that $\mathbf{D}_{\mathbf{y}} F(0)$ is invertible because the leading 1s might not all end up in the last $m$ columns.

Comment: This is an *assumption* when we state the implicit function theorem. *Some* $m$ columns must form an invertible matrix. To make explicit the notation in working with this theorem, we assume it's the last columns.

Comment: @TedShifrin Actually, this is a slight variation of the inverse function theorem where we only assume that the function  $f$ is from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and that its derivative is rank m.

Comment: If $D_yF(0)$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, and $m\ne n$, then it certainly **isn't** invertible.

Comment: $D_yF(0)$ is an $mxm$ *sub*matrix. I have edited the question @GerryMyerson

Comment: Sam, I believe you'll find that that "slight variation" is in fact the implicit function theorem :P

Comment: @TedShifrin Except the implicit function theoremm requres that the matrix Dyf(0) is invertible. I only know that Df(0)=[Dxf(0),Dyf(0)]  an $m\times n$ matrix (not $m\times m$ is rank m. my question is how does this lead to Dyf(0) being invertible?

Comment: Did you read my first comment?

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you it turns out my professor made a typo which caused this confusion

Comment: You might check out (some of) my YouTube videos, linked in my profile.